# generate hash on ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

On production server:

```rb
"KYK_iphone3.jpg".hash.abs%1000
=> 908
```

But on staging server:

```rb
"KYK_iphone3.jpg".hash.abs%1000
=> 740
```

The two hashes do not match. Can you please give me your ideas on what to do in this situation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ruby's default hashing is not guaranteed to be consistent across implementations. You should use a standardized hashing algorithm such as MD5, SHA1 or similar, if you require consistent hashes.

**EDIT:**
On further investigation, it turns out it is not even consistent across different processes:

```
$ irb
> "abc".hash
 => 3669021835949727595
> exit 
$ irb
> "abc".hash
 => 2091809102525897616
```

It appears this might be an [intended security feature inherited from Perl](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl581delta.html#Hash-Randomisation) to protect against [algorithmic complexity attacks](http://www.cs.rice.edu/~scrosby/hash/CrosbyWallach_UsenixSec2003.pdf).